# How to avoid windows to unmazimize when clicking title bar in ubuntugnome

Tags: gnome, titlebar, maximized

I'm not sure what changed in my environment, but today I started noticing some behavior I don't like:

If I have a window maximized and I click the title of the window, the window unmaximize. I know this behavior wasn't there before because that is normally how I change from one window to another using my mouse and I just starting to notice this.

The question is: How can I prevent GNOME from unmaximizing my window when I single click the title bar on a maximized window?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of waiting (I'm very impatient), I decided to do a research myself and I remembered that there was couple of extensions I upgraded in the past couple of days so  went ahead and disabled one by one my extensions until I found the offender. Apparently the ShellTile extension recently upgraded and they introduced this very annoying feature, disabling the extension gets everything back to normal.